# How do I change the icon of an item from a xml layout?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change `android:icon="@android:drawable/picture"`. 
For some reason it can't find the picture. The picture is in every drawable folder. If I want to change the application icon from an android manifest file by using `android:icon="@android:drawable/picture"`, it can find it there, but not in the layout file.

Where should I add the picture in order for android studio to find it?

I know that there are other solved questions regarding this problem but those are not helping me. I tried them .

Comment: try using with `@+id`

Comment: use "@drawable/picture" ... remove android

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I don't know how I missed that. Thank you.Actually it won't change the picture .. Now I'm able to find it but in the app the picture is not changed xD

Comment: android:icon isn't available in a layout file but is present for a manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the icon from a layout file as it is not available for it but is available for an application tag.

Read about application tag and layout tag here .

[Manifest tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html)

[Layout tag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)